# Phantomjs/Casperjs is not evaluating the JS/Ajax on the German amazon site properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, casperjs

i got a problem with the german Amazon site.

This Url http://www.amazon.de/Angebote/b/ref=cs_top_nav_gb27?ie=UTF8&node=872398 links to the german Amazon-Deal site.

On the Site is a section called "Aktuelle Blitzangebote" which offers  serval deals over the day at a specific time.

Somehow the deals within the 'ul.ulResized' (the deal in the "Aktuelle Blitzangebote box) are not loaded if I try to access them via phantomjs.

I use the following script to grab the HTML-src from the site:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    pageSettings: {
                 userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
                  viewportSize: {width: 1600, height: 900}
     }

});
var fs = require('fs');

 var address = casper.cli.args[0].replace(/\^/g,"");

 console.log("Address == " + address);

casper.on('remote.message', function (msg) {
      this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.start(address);

casper.wait(5000);
casper.then(function()
       {
           console.log("writing");
           fs.write("blitz.html", this.getHTML(), "w");
           console.log("done");
       });

casper.run();
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Best regards,
Ogofo

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var url = 'http://www.amazon.de/Angebote/b/ref=cs_top_nav_gb27?ie=UTF8&node=872398';

    var casper = require('casper').create({
        verbose: false,
        logLevel: 'debug'
    });

    casper.test.comment('Starting Testing');
    casper.start(url, function() {
        console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());

        this.test.assertHttpStatus(200, siteName + ' is up');

        this.wait(5000, function(){
            console.log(this.getHTML(".ulResized "));
        });

    });

    casper.run(function() {
        this.echo('So the whole suite ended.');
        this.exit();
    });
```

You should also be able to select specific `<li>` by using this:

```
console.log(this.getHTML(".ulResized li:nth-child(1)")); //replace 1 with list order number
```